# Tensorflow binary classification training loss won't decrease, accuracy stuck at around 50%

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm fairly new to this, and could use some advice on where to go from here.

I'm using tensorflow 2.3.0 with keras to build a binary classification model.  I am unable to share the dataset since it's proprietary data owned by my company, but the features are all numerical financial data, representing a sort of histogram for a customer.

I've tried two models, one with 300 features and one with 600, the one with 600 simply representing a longer history.  The features are normalized first, and the labels are all 0 or 1, to indicate whether the account should be flagged or not.

I have 500,000 training samples, and 60,000 test samples.  The 0/1 label split is roughly half.

This is the code I have currently:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make numpy values easier to read.
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import utils

features = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
labels = np.array(features.pop('target'))
features = np.array(features)
num_features = features.shape[1]
features = utils.normalize(features)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(num_features,)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss = tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(features, labels, epochs=100)
```

This is likely the wrong topology, it's just my most recent attempt. I have tried a few different topologies - ranging from tiny single-layer networks with a small number of units to what you see here.  I have tried different learning rates and epochs, and with or without the dropout.  All of them give basically this same pattern:

```
Epoch 1/100
15625/15625 [==============================] - 46s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5113
Epoch 2/100
15625/15625 [==============================] - 46s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.5127
Epoch 3/100
15625/15625 [==============================] - 46s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.5135
Epoch 4/100
15625/15625 [==============================] - 47s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6928 - accuracy: 0.5142
Epoch 5/100
15625/15625 [==============================] - 48s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6928 - accuracy: 0.5138
```

The loss essentially flatlines here and the accuracy hovers around this point.  If I use a very high learning rate the loss starts high but eventually flatlines around this same point.

To test if the model is working at all, I tried with a very small subset of the data (only 5 rows or so), and it quickly reduces the loss to near zero with 100% accuracy, which of course is greatly overfit but was only meant to test the code/data.

What are some next steps I can try to improve this?  Does this look like maybe just poorly designed features that the NN can't figure out how to correlate, or is this perhaps not the right choice of algorithm?

EDIT:

Based on comments and responses (thanks!), I've tried a few more tweaks and I'm making some progress.  I've adjusted the batch size, tweaked the topology, and lowered the learning rate.  I also didn't really understand how validation data fit into the picture, so I have been running a training session now with `validation_split=0.2` - my new problem is that now my training loss is decreasing/accuracy increasing, but the inverse is true for the validation loss/accuracy.  Here's some epoch snapshots:

```
Epoch 1/1000
1563/1563 [==============================] - 25s 16ms/step - loss: 0.6926 - accuracy: 0.5150 - val_loss: 0.6927 - val_accuracy: 0.5134

Epoch 20/1000
1563/1563 [==============================] - 24s 15ms/step - loss: 0.6746 - accuracy: 0.5760 - val_loss: 0.7070 - val_accuracy: 0.5103

Epoch 50/1000
1563/1563 [==============================] - 24s 15ms/step - loss: 0.5684 - accuracy: 0.7015 - val_loss: 0.8222 - val_accuracy: 0.5043
```

I assume this is overfitting in action?

Comment: try standard adam learning rate of 1e-5

Comment: That's a lot of strong dropout! My suggestion is to remove it altogether and see how it performs, and then gradually add what you need. Remember that dropout is mostly for regularization so if you are stuck in random-guessing performance, I would start by deregularizing everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the dense layer units to 512,128,64,1. Remove all dropout layers except the last one. Set the drop out rate of the last one to something like .3. Use your test samples as validation data so you can see if the model is over/under fitting. Also recommend you try using an adjustable learning using the keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau, and early stopping using the keras callback EarlyStopping. Documentation is [here.][1] Set each callback to monitor validation loss. My suggested code is shown below:

```
reduce_lr=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
          monitor="val_loss",factor=0.5, patience=2, verbose=1)
e_stop=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( monitor="val_loss", patience=5, 
          verbose=0,  restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks=[reduce_lr, e_stop]
```

In model.fit include

```
callbacks=callbacks
```

Comment: I've combined your suggestions along with some of the comments and I'm making progress, but I do think I now have an overfitting problem.  See my edits.

Comment: yes it is classical over fitting did you leave a dropout layer in the model? If so increase the rate. If that does not solve it add an additional drop out layer. If that does not work reduce the number of dense units. See my modified answer

Comment: I did leave the dropout in, I will try experimenting with it some more and adjusting the units along with the callbacks.  Will report back with results, thanks for the advice.  I think you have steered me in the right direction, so I will mark this as the answer.  Cheers